# Setting the newly created Material float value with material.SetFloat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**In my program, I want to spawn 3D Objects of Cisterns filled with water  to a certain level.**

I've created a Shader that has a `Fill` float property which indicates the water level in the water tank. I assign that shader to another 3D Object which is inside the Cistern object (Cistern object has Glass material, Water object has Water material with special shader).

Here are the [Shader Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ZTz.jpg) screenshots

Here how it looks like (even though the water level is wrong) -> [Water tanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyp5u.png)

```cs
foreach (var cistern in _cisInfo) //Spawning Cisterns
{
    //...Calculating position, scale and fill value of next Cistern & Water to be spawned

    Instantiate(cisternPrefabGameObject, _upcomingSpawnPosition, _rotationToSpawn);
    LiquifyObject(ref waterPfGameObject, fillValue);
    GameObject water = Instantiate(waterPfGameObject, _upcomingWaterSpawnPosition, _rotationToSpawn);
}
```

**Now whenever I create new Material** (I'm assigning unique Materials with a certain Fill value to every Cistern) **from Shader constructor** and set its `Fill` float value, and then `Instantiate` the water object, the `Fill` value of in-game generated 3D object Material seems to not change at all, it's stuck at -0.25 value which I set before as default.

LiquifyObject function

```cs
void LiquifyObject(ref GameObject go, float fillValue)
{
    Material mat = new Material(waterShader);
    mat.SetFloat("_Fill", fillValue);
    go.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mat;
}
```

I've tried checking the Fill float value by `waterModel.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial.GetFloat("_Fill")` function and the `Fill` value of Material just before Instantiating seems to be fine.

Am I missing the point somewhere?

I haven't used Unity before, sorry for the heavy misconceptions.

Comment: Is the property really called `Fill`? Usually the convention is that shader properties start with `_` so it would be `_Fill` .. note that the name you see in the Inspector of the Material is not the same as the actual Property name! Could you post the shader code? Also in general why solve this is a shader at all and not simply the size of the object?

Comment: Once I faced problems setting  the material problems and solved them using a [MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)

Comment: @derHugo I've added a `_` at the start of the property name in code, and nothing really changed. I've created Shader with the `Create > Shader > URP > Unlit Shader Graph` option. Here's a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/TAdMp1d

Comment: @poisson can't really see anything in the image .. do you have a better quality? And please most importantly include the actual property settings for your property!

Comment: @derHugo i've edited the post, here is the link https://imgur.com/a/EmdCujo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As guessed you are using the wrong name.

Note that the name of the property is `Fill` **but** that's only the **display name**!

What you want to use in code is what is configured as **`Reference`**! See [Shader Properties](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Property-Types.html)

> **Reference Name**: The internal name used for the property inside the shader

and further

> NOTE: If you overwrite the Reference Name parameter be aware of the following conditions:
>
> - **If your Reference Name does not begin with an underscore, one will be automatically appended.**
> - If your Reference Name contains any characters which are unsupported in HLSL they will be removed.
> - You can revert to the default Reference Name by right clicking on it and selecting Reset Reference

Currently yours is

```
"Vector1_afe......"
```

I would suggest you change it to something meaningful like `_Fill` since this is the usual convention for property references.

---

In general for performance reasons you should cach property IDs using [`Shader.PropertyToID`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.PropertyToID.html) like

```
private readonly int _FillID = Shader.PropertyToID("_Vector1_afe...");
```

or after setting a proper reference id

```
private readonly int _FillID = Shader.PropertyToID("_Fill");
```

and then rather use this `_FillID` for `SetFloat`.

```
mat.SetFloat(_FillID, fillValue);
```